# Providing options to an InlineEdit Dropdown Select

Tags: magento-2.1, uicomponent

I am creating a new module that includes the InlineEdit functionality of the UIComponent grid. It's simple to get it working with a simple `text` input. However, there is neither documentation nor an example of using the `select` input.

So if you use XML like the following to build your grid, it will add the `text_column` column and the `store_id` column and make them editable on click.

```
<listing>
    ...
    <columns name="company_module_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    ...
                    <item name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="company/module/inlineEdit"/>
                        <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">company_module.company_module.company_module_columns_editor</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <column name="text_column">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Text Column</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="store_id" class="Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                        <!-- What do I need to do in this area to provide this dropdown with the proper data? -->
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to provide data to the dropdown select.** If I change it to a `text` it pulls in the store name, and makes the name editable. But with `select` and no `options` provided, it just gives me an empty `select`, so the form parameters passed to my controller don't include the store field.

I tried several things, the latest being `<item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store\Options</item>`, which I found on a standard UiComponent form in core Magento2.

Answer (score 4):

Check if this code works:

```
<column name="store_id">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store\Options</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store</item>
            <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Comment: Great suggestion, this does work in that it fills the dropdown with the stores. However, it no longer shows the store before activating the inline editor. I tried adding the class back to the `column`, and moving the `options` to different levels, but they seem to conflict. I'm only able to get one to work at a time--either the stores display in the grid on load, or they display in the dropdown select on edit.